# coupon code prefix, generation and reusability

Tags: php, database-design, code-generation, prefix, coupon

Say I have an event which giveaway `1000` coupons in the format of `FVE58ZBBQKUI` (`FVE` is the prefix) which are randomly generated alphanumerically.

After the event is finished, all the coupon codes and the event will be removed from database.

my question is do I need to always create unique prefix for every event or is there a way to reuse the same prefix in the future?

If I reuse the same prefix then IF someone inserted the same old code from an old event then they might be able to redeem the coupon although very unlikely since the coupon is generated randomly alphanumerically

Comment: Why remove anything? Link the coupons to the event and give the event an expiry date. Then when checking a coupon code look up that date.

Comment: I see, do you mean that I should not remove any event at all even after they expired? but it will accumulate. For the prefix, I only have 4 char prefix, the combination is pretty limited, should I make it longer?

Comment: I don't know. Why do you have a prefix at all? What is it good for?

Comment: I have a 9 char coupon code + 4 char prefix, do you mean I should share the 9 char coupon code range with all events? I think that will cause collision and the available range of code options will be lesser and lesser as more new events are create

Comment: I just wonder why this is 4 chars prefix plus 9 chars code and not simply 13 chars code. What is that prefix good for?